# Pre-select Select or Mult-Select options from the existing ones instead of adding and selecting a new option

Tags: php, mysql, select, fetch, multi-select

This code retrieves and displays the customer's account information from the database and pre-selects the values matching  their information.

The problem is that instead of selecting from amongst the existing Select or Mult-Select options it is adding and selecting a new option with the relevant value/s. How can I correct it so that it selects from the existing options?

```
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $rows['notifications']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['notifications']; ?></option>
```

The full code is:

```
<?php     
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE customer_info.user_id=$user_id ") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result );
?>

<label>Notifications:</label><select name="notifications[]" class="multi" multiple="multiple" style="width:10em;">
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $rows['notifications']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['notifications']; ?></option>
<option value="New_Items">New items</option>
<option value="Sale_Items">Sale items</option>                        
<option value="Profile_Matches">Items matching my profile</option>
</select>

<label>Gift Program:</label>
<select name="gift_privacy" style="width:20em;">
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $rows['gift_privacy']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['gift_privacy']; ?></option>
<option value="Standard">Standard settings</option>
<option value="Gift_ID_Req">Require program ID</option>
<option value="Not_Enrolled">Do not enroll</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<label>Gift Program:</label>
<select name="gift_privacy" style="width:20em;">
   <option <?php if($rows['notifaction] === "Standard") echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="Standard">Standard settings</option>
   <option <?php .... ?> value="Gift_ID_Req">Require program ID</option>
   <option <?php .... ?> value="Not_Enrolled">Do not enroll</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think there might be a typo of sorts because the page stopped loading when I added this :-(

Comment: @ChayaCooper Well there are periods in it where further code should be. I am just giving you some pseudocode on how you can do what you asked.

Comment: I realize that ;-) The code I used for the 2nd example was <select name="gift_privacy"> <option <?php if($rows['gift_privacy] === "Standard") echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="Standard">Standard settings</option> <option <?php if($rows['gift_privacy] === "Gift_ID_Req") echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="Gift_ID_Req">Require program ID</option> <option <?php if($rows['gift_privacy] === "Not_Enrolled") echo 'selected="selected'; ?> value="Not_Enrolled">Do not enroll</option> </select>

Comment: I just realized that the reason that this wasn't working was because it needed to call $row (the value before str_replace) instead of $rows (the value after str_replace). Once I changed that it worked for the standard Select elements, but it doesn't work properly with the multi-select elements because it stops pre-selecting values if there is more than one value in the column.